# Double errors correcting

Tags: hamming-code

Is there a method to correct double errors using Hamming code?

Answer (score 0):

No. But there are [other coding schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) that do this.

Comment: i hope to ensure .... my thesis in Hamming code , i discovered new method based in hamming to correct double errors by using multistage >>>> new hamming ( 10 , 4 ) to detect and correct up to double errors ..... so plz any one have more information about this topic , tell us

Answer (score 0):

Actually yes.  Hamming codes are capable of double error correction.
You just need to increase the Hamming distance from 3 to 5.

In his original paper, Hamming talked a lot about the (7,4) Hamming code, so
now whenever you google Hamming code you get that information and not much
more.  The (7,4) code is a perfect code, so it is pretty useful.

Double error correction codes are going to be less efficient.
For a block length of n=7, I could only find two codewords at a Hamming
distance of 5 away from each other that do not overlap with others.
For a block length of n=10, I could only achieve 8 codewords.  That would make it a (10,3) code.  That's a lot better than just repeating the message
5 times (which would be a (15,3) code), but there are a lot better ways
to do this.